# My pc laptop won't connect to ethernet but only wifi/ wifi extender

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ethernet

I have two wifi extenders at my house. My pc will always connect to one of them instead of my primary wifi when it boots up. I solved this by using this command in cmd `route delete 0.0.0.0`

But then it will connect to my primary wifi, which is also painfully slow, and I want to force it to connect to ethernet, but it never goes the way I want it to. I tried to keep turning off and on my router, reboot Windows 7. It will eventually success to connect to the ethernet sometimes, but are there faster ways to do this? I don't want to keep turning off and on my router because my family is using the wifi

Comment: For whatever reason, computers like to take WiFi over Ethernet without question. Disable WiFi on your computer if you want to use Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use wifi along with ethernet, you can disable the wifi adaptor in device manager itself.

Comment: I disabled the wifi adapter, but there is no ethernet? The ethernet cable is plugged in

Comment: can you please share outputs of below commands 
1. netsh interface show interface
2. ipconfig /all

Comment: https://ibb.co/9gxGFT8

Comment: according to this image, you only have RTL8723B USB WiFi card. have you installed ethernet card drivers correctly ? can you check "netsh interface show interface" as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the result https://ibb.co/zHztrdB

Comment: How do I know if I have the correct ethernet card driver installed?

Comment: This new screenshot confirms that only your wifi adaptor is avaiable. Can you please follow [this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/284/) guide and check `Network Adapters` in the `Device Manager`. Also please check for `Other Devices` as per [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/193798/how-to-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices-in-the-device-manager/). You may find the ethernet adapter in there, if drivers are not installed. If it is not available on either places, please check BIOS and confirm whether `Onboard LAN` is enabled if you want to use onboard LAN adapter